# Keep maximum of repeated observations

Tags: r

I have a data frame with several student IDs and the scores they obtained on various tests. However, there are instances where a student took the same test multiple times. I would like to only keep their highest score.

For example, I would like to turn

```
Student Subject Score
1 Math 96
1 Math 97
1 English 82
2 Math 85
2 English 72
2 English 75
```

into

```
Student Subject Score
1 Math 97
1 English 82
2 Math 85
2 English 75
```

I have tried

```
df[!duplicated(df[,c(1,2)]),]
```

but that just keeps the first of the repeated observations. How could I adjust this to keep the maximum?

Comment: Are there other columns you might need to keep as well? You could just use `dplyr`'s group by if not: `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(Student, Subject) %>% summarize(Score = max(Score))`

Comment: `aggregate(Score ~ Student + Subject, data, max)`.

Comment: I don't have other columns I need to keep but I might in the future. Thank you!